# MSAL doesn't run WebView for login

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I use MSAL in Xamarin.Forms to authenticate users in B2C. Version of MSAL 4.0.0, and Xamarin.Forms 3.2.0.871581. I noticed my MSAL doesn't run WebView for login user. I tried several solution but the problem is still there :-(
If anyone had such a problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't run WebView"?

Comment: Msal opens the Web View for authorize user in B2C on start the application. Later returns to application after authorize. In my UWP project it works ok, application is starting and window of login user with MSAL is opening at the same moment. In Android project MSAL doesn't open this window. Only application is starting. I didn't found why? Maybe MSAL doesn't work with Xamarin.Forms???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [B2C Xamarin sample which uses MSAL v4](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native). You can swamp out the values in [B2CConstants.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/blob/master/UserDetailsClient/UserDetailsClient.Core/Features/LogOn/B2CConstants.cs#L10) with your own B2C user journey values, and the sample should just work.

Note for Android, you need to set the Activity by using `.WithParentActivityOrWindow(ParentActivityOrWindow)` as done [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/blob/master/UserDetailsClient/UserDetailsClient.Core/Features/LogOn/B2CAuthenticationService.cs#L90) in the sample, so the token gets back once the interaction has happened. 
Basically this:

```
var authResult = AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
 .WithParentActivityOrWindow(parentActivity)
 .ExecuteAsync();
```

Also, on Android, you will need to override the `OnActivityResult` method of the `Activity`, as seen [here in the sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/blob/master/UserDetailsClient/UserDetailsClient.Droid/MainActivity.cs#L37)

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
     base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```